# How to solve this problem on Application of Derivative?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

[image]

My approach as follows :

As *f(0) = 0 = f(1)* let *f(x) = kx(x-1)*

*f'(x) = k(x-1) + kx*

*f''(x) = 2k*

Therefore, *2k - 2kx + 2k - 2kx + kx(x-1) >= e^x*

*kx^2 - 5kx + 4k >= e^x*

Since, *e^x is always positive ;*

Therefore, *k > 0 and D < 0*

*25k^2 - 16k^2 < 0*

*9k^2 < 0 OR k < 0*

From above, no value of *k* is possible.

Please help me to solve the question in the image. I cannot figure out further steps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a big hint for $1$.  Let's not try to guess the form of $f$, but rather use properties of the derivative at critical points.

Observe that $e^x$ has minimum of $1$ on $[0,1]$.

So $f''(x) - 2f'(x) + f(x) \geq 1$.

Now suppose f(x) takes a maximum at $x = x_0$.  Then $f'(x_0) = 0$.

So we have $f''(x_0) + f(x_0) \geq 1$.

But we know even more, because we know something about the value of $f''(x_0)$ when $f(x_0)$ is a local maximum (the graph is concave down!).  Use this to refine the last equality and then see which of the bounds on $f$ still make sense.